# Add to string if string non empty

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Sometime I want to join two strings with a space in between. But if second string is null, I don't want the space.

Consider following code:

```
void AssertFoo(bool cond, string message = null) {
    ...
    Assert.Fail("Something is foo.{0}", message != null ? " " + message : "");
    ...
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 27):

Here is one option that I like.  It's better if you already have an `IEnumerable<string>` with your data, but it's easy enough even if you don't.  It also clearly scales well to n strings being joined, not just 1 or two.

```
string[] myStrings = new string[]{"Hello", "World", null};
string result = string.Join(" ", myStrings.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)));
```

Here is another option.  It's a bit shorter for this one case, but it's uglier, harder to read, and not as extensible, so I would probably avoid it personally:

```
//note space added before {0}
Assert.Fail("Something is foo. {0}", message ?? "\b");
```

In this case we add the space to the format string itself, but if `message` is null we instead use the backspace character to remove the space that we know is before it in the message.

Comment: I considered that. I would like to have an option to use {0},{1},{2} if I need to. It also isn't more readable than what I already have.

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions of C# you can use the following extension method:

```
public static string Prepend(this string value, string prepend) => prepend + value;
```

It can be used like this:

```
Assert.Fail("Something is foo.{0}", message?.Prepend(" "));
```

**Added in 2020:**

Today I use this:

```
public static string Surround(this object value, string prepend, string append = null) => prepend + value + append;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.Fail("Something is foo.{0}", (" " + message).TrimEnd());
```

Sure, this will result in a few string object creations, but it's unlikely such micro-optimization issues would matter in the vast majority of programs. It might be considered an advantage of this method that it handles not just null message, but a message of all whitespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string joinedString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(message2) ? message1 : message1 + " " + message2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C#6  you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) like this:

```
$"Something is foo. {mssg}".TrimEnd();
```

See it in [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lueDWq)

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.Fail("Something is foo.{0}", message?.PadLeft(message.Lenght + 1, ' '));
```

Answer (score -6):

The most elegant way is to use the inbuilt keyword of String class.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty
```

This way you wont have a problem.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.